# Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. > java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

Tags: gradle, nullpointerexception, react-native

I'm trying to use react-native for the first time, so I don't have much of a clue what I'm doing. I've been trying to get the emulator from android studio to work in conjunction with npx react-native start in VS Code. Is there anyone that knows how to fix this error?

BUILD FAILED in 1m 10s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up:
https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Comment: its kinda hard to assess the issue at this point, the easiest way is firing up the android studio open the android project and look at the build/issue tab

Comment: from the stack trace above, it seems the android environment is not correctly set up. Go through the docs again and make sure it is set up. Make sure the environment variables are in place